# FreeBSD istgt - how to limit iscsi target discoverability to IP address

Tags: freebsd, iscsi, truenas

How can I setup an ISCSI target that is only visible to a certain IP address?  For example, if a client runs iscsiadm discover from 10.1.1.130, I only want target iqn.2011-03.domain.org.istgt.ded130 shown to him.

I've tried setting up multiple InitatorGroups, but that does not appear to make any difference to what is displayed.  If the InitiatorGroup does not limit discoverability, what is it used for?

For example from my istgt.conf file:

```
# InitiatorGroup section
[InitiatorGroup1]
  InitiatorName "DED30"
  Netmask 10.1.1.130/30

[InitiatorGroup2]
  InitiatorName "DED24"
  Netmask 10.1.1.124/30
[LogicalUnit1]
  TargetName "ded130"
  TargetAlias "ded130"
  Mapping PortalGroup1 InitiatorGroup1
  AuthMethod None
  UseDigest Auto
  ReadOnly No
  UnitType Disk
  UnitOnline yes
  BlockLength 512
  QueueDepth 32
  LUN0 Storage /mnt/tank/ded138_ds/ded138_extent 1000GB
```